# get rid of multiple words using sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm trying to get rid of the following input using sed:

```
branch
branch

not
"git
"git
```

That is an empty line, the term branch, not and "git. However the following line does not work:

```
git status  2>&1  | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/^$//g' | sed 's/^branch||^not||^changes||^"git//g'
```

How can I write this line correctly to get rid of all of this at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of doing what you are trying to achieve:

```
git status --porcelain | sed s/^...//
```

From `git help status`:

> --porcelain[=]
>   Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output.

---

And here is what you want to use with your commands:

Using `sed`:

```
... | sed -r '/(^"git|^branch|^not|^$)/d'
```

Using `grep`:

```
... | grep -Ev '^branch|^not|^"git|^$'
```

Which returns file names from your `git` and `awk` command.

Comment: @user99201 You're welcome ;)